# SSH to aws ec2 connection close like this

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

ssh into an aws-ec2-instance closew with below message

```
    OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
    debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
    debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
    debug1: Connecting to ec2-13-222.222.222.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com [13-222.222.222] port 22.
    debug1: Connection established.
    debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
    debug1: identity file app-api-v2-2.pem type -1
    debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
    debug1: identity file app-api-v2-2.pem-cert type -1
    debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
    debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
    debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
    debug1: Authenticating to ec2-13-222.222.222.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com:22 as 'ubuntu'
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
    debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
    debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
    debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
    debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
    debug1: Server host key: XXXXXXX-xxx-xxx
SHA256:xxXXXxXxxXXxx/XXxxxXXXXxxxXXXX
    debug1: Host 'ec2-13-222.222.222.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
    debug1: Found key in /home/rayan/.ssh/known_hosts:13
    debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
    debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
    debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
    debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
    debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:XXXXXXXXXXXxxXXXXXXxxXXXxxxxxXXX
    Connection closed by 13.222.222.222 port 22
```

I changed my key-pair but It also didnt worked. Do this have any connection to my recent withdrawl from paid Developer support from aws. I am using ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Helps appeciated.

Comment: You need to check the logs on the server to find out why it happened.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, I changed my instance type and the issue solved.